# How to find which subclasses of given class implement a particular interface in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, subclass, hierarchy

I need to browse, in large project, subclasses of given class A implementing a particular interface B.

Is there in Eclipse any way to filter Type Hierarchy of subclasses of A to only those who implement interface B, or to filter hierarchy of classes implementing interface B to subclasses of class A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the java search in two steps:

Assuming subclasses `C1` and `C3` of `A` implement `B`, but `C2` does not:

In the first step, select class `A` and search for all subclasses of A using the java search (Search->Java...) with option implementors:

[image]

Then the search view pops up and we see all subclasses of A:

[image]

Select them and hit "Search->Java..." again. Now we can search within this selection for implementors of `B`.

[image]

This gives us subclasses of `A` that implement `B`:

[image]

Comment: That was my first thought but unfortunately 'implementors' only finds **direct** implementors of the type, unlike Type Hierarchy which finds all implementors. Also you can't select the items in the Type Heirarchy to use as your 'selected items' in a search.. It's very frustrating.

Comment: Procedure presented by donttrythat works well, however it has the important drawback spotted by xtratic. Thank you very much @donttrythat for your time and detailed description.